# C++ does compiler automatically use std::move constructor for local variable that is going out of scope?

Tags: c++, optimization, move, copy-constructor, move-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Class1 {
    string s;
public:
    Class1(const string& s_) : s(s_) {}        
};

class Class2 {
    string s;
public:
    Class2(string s_) : s(std::move(s_)) {}
};

class Class3 {
    string s;
public:
    Class3(string s_) : s(s_) {}
};


int main()
{
    string str = "ABC";
    Class1 a(str);
    Class2 b(str);
    Class3 c(str);
}
```

I'm trying to find the cost of my constructor.

- Class 1: cost 1 copy constructor
- Class 2: cost 1 copy constructor and 1 move constructor
- Class 3: cost 1 copy constructor + {A. nothing, B. move constructor, C. copy constructor}

Is the compiler smart enough to copy `str` directly into `c.s` ?  What is the answer for the 3rd case?

**Big edit:** using a vector-like class, the answer is C. But is there any reason why the compiler can't steal `s_` even when the object will be destructed after `s(s_)` ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename T = int>
class MyVector {
private:
    int n;
    T* data;
public:
    MyVector() {
        n = 0;
        data = nullptr;
        cout << "MyVector default constructor\n";
    }

    MyVector(int _n) {
        n = _n;
        data = new T[n];
        cout << "MyVector param constructor\n";
    }

    MyVector(const MyVector& other) {
        n = other.n;
        data = new T[n];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) data[i] = other.data[i];
        cout << "MyVector copy constructor\n";
    }

    MyVector(MyVector&& other) {
        n = other.n;
        data = other.data;
        other.n = 0;
        other.data = nullptr;
        cout << "MyVector move constructor\n";
    }

    MyVector& operator = (const MyVector& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            n = other.n;
            delete[] data;
            data = new T[n];
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) data[i] = other.data[i];
        }
        cout << "MyVector copy assigment\n";
        return *this;
    }

    MyVector& operator = (MyVector&& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            n = other.n;
            delete[] data;
            data = other.data;
            other.n = 0;
            other.data = nullptr;
        }
        cout << "MyVector move assigment\n";
        return *this;
    }

    ~MyVector() {
        delete[] data;
        cout << "MyVector destructor: size = " << n << "\n";
    }

    int size() {
        return n;
    }
};

class Class1 {
    MyVector<> s;
public:
    Class1(const MyVector<>& s_) : s(s_) {}        
};

class Class2 {
    MyVector<> s;
public:
    Class2(MyVector<> s_) : s(std::move(s_)) {}
};

class Class3 {
    MyVector<> s;
public:
    Class3(MyVector<> s_) : s(s_) {}
};


int main()
{
    MyVector<> vec(5);
    cout << "-----------\n";
    
    cout << "Class1\n";
    Class1 a(vec);
    cout << "\n------------\n";

    cout << "Class3\n";
    Class2 b(vec);
    cout << "\n------------\n";

    cout << "Class3\n";
    Class3 c(vec);
    cout << "\n------------\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `std::string`, use your own class and add useful outputs to its constructors. Then you will see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s_` is a lvalue in the initializer `s(s_)`. So the copy constructor will be used to construct `s`. There is not automatic move like e.g. in return statements. The compiler is not allowed to elide this constructor call.

Of course a compiler can always optimize a program in whatever way it wants as long as observable behavior is unchanged. Since you cannot observe copies of a string being made if you don't take addresses of the string objects, the compiler is free to optimize the copies away in any case.

If you take a constructor argument to be stored in a member by-value, there is no reason not to use `std::move`.

Comment: so is the answer A, B, or C?

Comment: @HuyLe The answer is C, the copy constructor will be used to construct the member.